# Use value of a variable as counter in python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, counter

I want to take an input from the user and and store it in a variable, lets say `k`. Then use this `k` as a counter for a `for loop`.

`while i<k:` doesn't work!
code:

```
k= input('number of points:')
p=[]
i=0
while i<k:
x=float(input('Enter value='))
p.append(x)
i=i+1
```

Output:

```
number of points:3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ramupradip/tes.py", line 4, in <module>
while i<k:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

I also tried using range

```
for i in range(1,k)
```

which gave me an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ramupradip/reflect.py", line 6, in 
    for i in range(1,k):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: what is k.....? is it `int`?Plz post errors that you getting

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the input like this:

```
k = int(input('enter counter: '))
```

... I guess you forgot to convert the number to `int`, but it's impossible to tell if you don't show the relevant code. Other than that, the looping constructs shown in the question should work fine, but the first one is preferred in Python, just be careful with the indexes:

```
for i in range(1, k+1):
    # do something
```

Equivalently:

```
i = 1
while i <= k:
    # do something
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you :) . It was the missing 'int' which was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That does not make any sense.
You could want this:

```
for i in range(k):
     ...
```

Where `k` is the total number of *iterations* set by the user and `i` is a value that changes from `0` to `k - 1`.
Or you could want this:

```
for k in range(x):
     ...
```

Where `k` is a value from `0` to `x - 1` and the user input doesn't mean anything. Or you could want this:

```
for i in range(k, x):
    ...
```

Where `k` is the start value set by the user, `x` is a value set by the program and `i` is a value that starts from `k` and ends in `x - 1`

See the documentation for more info http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: You're changing the starting value of `i`, this is not equivalent to the code in the question. It _might_ be possible that OP is only interested in looping `k` times (we can't tell by just looking at the current question), but if he is going to use `i`, the expected starting value is `1`, according to the question